# Is it impossible to describe Jacobian of hyperelliptic curves by an explicit equation?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $C$ be a hyperelliptic curve and $J(C)$ be its Jacobian.
$J(C)$ is abelian variety, especially, projective variety, so it should have equation which defines $J(C)$.

$J(C)$ should be defined by equations, but it is almost impossible to describe its equation by hand?

(For example, Let $C$ be hyperelliptic curve given by equation $y^{19}=x^2(1-x)$. What is an explicit equation of $J(C)$ ?)

Comment: What research did you do? For instance, with some light searching there's a Transactions of the AMS article called ["Equations for the Jacobian of a hyperelliptic curve"](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1998-350-08/S0002-9947-98-02056-X/S0002-9947-98-02056-X.pdf) which at least sounds like it could be helpful - did you skim it? Were there things you liked/didn't like about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $J(C)$ can be described in a very explicit way, see Section 4 in [M. A. Reid, The complete intersection of two or more quadrics].